# code working fine on Perl 5.12.1 doesn't work on 5.10.0

Tags: perl

I wrote some code (about 100 lines) that is working fine on version 5.12.1.
Unfortunately my client is using version 5.10.0. So I tested the code on 5.10.0 and found it doesn't work!

Where can I find a list of differences between 5.10 and 5.12?

---

#### Edit:

I think the best answer to the question of "Where can I find a list of differences between 5.10 and 5.12" is [plusplus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89093/plusplus)' comment under the "accepted answer". For the explanation of the code below, please read [Michael Carman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235147/code-working-fine-on-perl-5-12-1-doesnt-work-on-5-10-0/3241258#3241258).

---

The code that works on 5.12.1 but does not work on 5.10.0 (`$contents` is still an empty string after running the code)

```
# read in the first 10 lines.
my $contents = '';
for (my $i = 0; $i < 10 && ! eof; $i++) {
    $contents .= <FILE>;
}
```

The improved code that works on both versions.

```
# read in the first 10 lines.
my $contents = '';
my $i = 0;
while (<FILE>) {
    last if $i >= 10;
    $contents .= $_;
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Obviously your Heisenberg compensator is out of alignment and needs to be repolarized.  Or that's my best guess without seeing an error message.

Comment: Tied filehandles now have an additional method EOF which provides the EOF type.

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't a useful description. You need to tell us 1) what you expected it to do, and 2) what it actually did.

Comment: @Michael - I though the comment in the code is clear enough to tell you that I expected to read 10 lines from a file. "doesn't work" means that the code fails to do that on version 5.10. Anyway, I've edited the question to make my point more clear. Thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl.html#Miscellaneous) page. You''ll find the perldelta's there. Or post your code and have us look at it ;)

Comment: The code is about 100 lines. I'll try to find out those lines that cause the issue and post it here tomorrow. Thanks in advance! Good night!

Comment: because it's not immediately obvious from the titles, http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5120delta.html is the differences between the major version numbers 5.10 and 5.12.0 and http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5121delta.html is the differences between 5.12.0 and 5.12.1 - you'll need to check both, although the first will probably be most useful

Comment: I've posted my code in the question. Anyone know why the for  loop is not working on version 5.10?

Answer (score 9):

There's a bug in your first code sample. A bare `eof` reports status for the last filehandle read. On of the first pass through the loop you (presumably) haven't read anything yet; not anything from `FILE` anyway. It appears that the internal behavior of this *invalid* call changed. Under Perl 5.12.1 running `perl -E "say eof"` prints nothing. Under Perl 5.10.0 it prints "1".

Explicitly testing `eof(FILE)` should fix the problem.

Tangent: Your code isn't very idiomatic. A more perlish approach would be

```
my $content;
while(<$fh>) {
    if ( 1 .. 10 ) { $content .= $_ }
    else           { last }
}
```

The idioms used are:

- Use a lexical filehandle instead of a typeglob. (`$fh` instead of `FILE`)
- Use the range operator `..` to track the number of lines read. This form
  implicitly tests against the input line number `$.`.
- Don't explicitly test for EOF (let the loop handle it).
- Use `last` to break out of the loop early.

Comment: ahh..seems that this is the problem of my code snippet. I though `eof` worked in the same way as that in C

Comment: Good points in the "tangent"! Thanks! I am still thinking in a C/Java way. Need to be more perlish ;)